# CKEditor- Unable to set value of the property 'dir': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, ckeditor, fckeditor

I have downloaded CKEditor and using in our MVC project. Please refer below code

```
@{ Html.BeginForm("Save", "News", FormMethod.Post, new {@class="form-inline news-admin"}); }

 <div class="input">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ShortText, new { @class = "shorttext", @id="editor1",maxlength = "50" })</div>

@{ Html.EndForm(); }
```

CKeditor code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
            </script>
```

but it throws error like Unable to set value of the property 'dir': object is null or undefined in ckeditor.js. i don't know what is the real cause of this issue ? what's wrong on my code ?

Answer (score 0):

couple of things.  you can't override the id of a field on a for helper.  So your selector isn't ever going to catch the field.  If you are trying to initialize the editor, you aren't using the right code.  Try this

```
$('.shorttext').ckeditor();
```

we pass some parameters in the middle but I am not sure what your requirements are.  To pass them it looks like this

```
$('.shorttext').ckeditor({
    resize_enabled: false,
    toolbarCanCollapse: false, 
    etc...
});
```

Comment: Thanks!!! actually the problem is, am not included entire ckeditor folder to our project. added only the script because of this it throws error

Comment: can you please suggest me what are the items are necessary to include in that project ? whether entire ckeditor folder or only necessary files. may i know necessary file deatils required for ckeditor

Comment: we have a reference for ckeditor/ckeditor.js and ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js

Comment: yes we can refer both the scripts.but we need to add the ckeditor folder to project solution then only it works..so i need what are the files in ckeditor need to be added in project (am not asking reference).

Comment: I believe I installed it through nuget.  There are a ton of files in the folder.  We only have the 2 files mentioned that we reference.  I don't know what files those references use.

Comment: Ok Matt. Thanks for your prompt response.do you have idea about sending the ckeditor value through ajax call

Comment: ck editor ties the value to the field it is tied to.  so in your case $('.shorttext').val() should grab the value

Comment: no it is not like that..we need to get like " CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();"

Comment: it may work like that but remember you can't override the id of the field.  try changing that to ['ShortText']

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49572/discussion-between-sivarajini-and-matt-bodily)